# pandas equivalent to R series of multiple repeated numbers

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy

I want to create a simple vector of many repeated values. This is easy in R:

```
> numbers <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2,4), rep(3,3))
> numbers
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

However, if I try to do this in Python using pandas and numpy, I don't quite get the same thing:

```
numbers = pd.Series([np.repeat(1,5), np.repeat(2,4), np.repeat(3,3)])
numbers
0    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1       [2, 2, 2, 2]
2          [3, 3, 3]
dtype: object
```

What's the R equivalent in Python?

Comment: The R equivalent to below is `rep(1:3, 5:3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust how you use `np.repeat`

```
np.repeat([1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 3])

array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

Or with `pd.Series`

```
pd.Series(np.repeat([1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 3]))

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     3
10    3
11    3
dtype: int64
```

That said, the purest form to replicate what you've done in `R` is to use `np.concatenate` in conjunction with `np.repeat`.  It just isn't what I'd recommend doing.

```
np.concatenate([np.repeat(1,5), np.repeat(2,4), np.repeat(3,3)])

array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use the same syntax in python:

```py
>>> from datar.base import c, rep
>>>
>>> numbers = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,4), rep(3,3))
>>> print(numbers)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.